# How to listen for emails in Dart?

Tags: email, dart, listener

Exactly what it says on the tin - how do you listen for emails sent to a Gmail account? There's no support for this, apparently - I tried searching for a package on `pub`, but to no avail - the most relevant thing I could find is `mailer`, but that only sends emails.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis makes it easy to use the GMail API from Dart

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether you're writing code for dart2js, server-side or Flutter Dart. But here's the JavaScript quickstart showing usage of the Gmail API:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js

It should be straightforward to port to whichever flavor of Dart you're using.

Comment: I'm using server-side Dart - do I just use the `googleapis` plugin in `pub`? I don't know where to start, though, since there's zero examples for using the GMail API in Dart available online.

Comment: I don't know much about server side dart, but the link I posted above shows the API usage